# What will be the structure of cysteine at pH=4?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amino-acids

As per my understanding since pKa of RSH and the amino group is >4 hence they would be in cationic form while the acid should be in anionic form. So charge on cysteine would be +1. But while looking on internet i found that nowhere the RSH group is protonated.
Please someone clarify

Answer (score 2):

> ...hence they would be in cationic form

Protonated does not imply cationic form. Some conjugated acid/base pairs have a neutral and an anionic form (like the carboxylic acid/carboxylate pair).

The acid/base equilibrium of the thiol group is the following:

$\ce{R-SH <=> R-S- + H+}$

The left-hand side is called protonated, and the right-hand side is called deprotonated.

$\ce{R-SH2+}$ is not observed in aqueous solution.

> since pKa of RSH and the amino group is > 4

The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of the ammonium group is > 4. The amino group does not act as an acid in aqueous solution, and its $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ is too high to be able to deprotonate an amino group in aqueous solution.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/162474/are-there-separate-quantity-symbols-for-the-pka-of-a-substance-and-the-pka-of-it